# Invalid Default value in MySQL when using datetime with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to restore a database someone gave me for reference. I'm using MAMP as of the moment with PHP 5.6.10. I tried importing the SQL file given to me, however, it gives an error at this block:

```
CREATE TABLE `itg_civil_status` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `civilStatusName` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  `date_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

the line in question is:

```
`date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
```

And the error I get is

```
Invalid default value for 'date_created'
```

I already looked it up and there are answers saying that `datetime` should either be null or has a constant value by default. However, I've also read that as of PHP 5.6, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` is allowed for the `datetime` field. I also tried `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, and`NOW()`, but all to no avail.

Kindly note that I can't simply just go and change my friend from `datetime` to `timestamp` because for some reason, MySQL didn't allow me to do so.

I also tried using PHP 7 just to test but to no avail as well.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, this is MySQL. But what version of MySQL are you running? As of mysql 5.6.5, you can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with DATETIME fields, but not in prior versions (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: Oh damn, I think I'm using 5.5.42. Any ideas how to upgrade it?

Comment: The easiest approach would be to just convert it to a `timestamp`. Although, I don't think you can have more than one `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` per table as default.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no brackets after the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `itg_civil_status` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `civilStatusName` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```